# Why doesnt this catch my exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The below code fails with a Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache... error.`
Why doesn't it catch my exception in the try block ?

```
    WebElement listbox = driver.findElement( By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountryList"));
    Select listboxSelect = new Select(listbox);

    //the textbox on the right
    WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountriesSelected"));


    int attempts = 0;
    while(textbox.getText() != Contry && attempts < 5)
    {
        attempts++;
        //make your selection in the select list
        listboxSelect.selectByVisibleText(Contry);

        //click the add button( or use the double click action )
        //addCountryButton.click();
        action3.perform();
        System.out.println("before the try");
        //wait for the textbox to be populated
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("try no "+attempts);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountriesSelected"), Contry));

        }
        catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        }catch (Error e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Stack trace of exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 1.11 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
System info: host: 'LCDKHQ087061', ip: '192.168.2.104', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: d0861e29-c67b-43ec-beb2-00c4bf29e38e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=25.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:152)
    at mytestpack.JavaExport.DocContrySiteRole(JavaExport.java:250)
    at mytestpack.UseInformationArray.UseArray(UseInformationArray.java:24)
    at mytestpack.mytestclass.main(mytestclass.java:33)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
System info: host: 'LCDKHQ087061', ip: '192.168.2.104', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.cache.getElementAt(resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7615)
    at <anonymous class>.Utils.getElementAt(file:///C:/Users/hlyl/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7115004136812534907webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7233)
    at <anonymous class>.WebElement.getElementText(file:///C:/Users/hlyl/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7115004136812534907webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10292)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/hlyl/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7115004136812534907webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10844)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/hlyl/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7115004136812534907webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:396)
```

Comment: Can you attach the stack trace of the exception? I mean are you sure if comes from the wait.until bit

Comment: The exception is not thrown in your try but somewhere else I suppose.

Comment: Edited to include error message..

Comment: as hgoebl suggest, check the line number where it is getting originated, i too suspect it is not part of try catch

Comment: Stack trace not readable. Find the part where your code is mentioned the first time.

Comment: `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountriesSelected` this element id i can see also used in outside of try-cath, there might be the exception arrised. As `StaleElementReferenceException` is `RuntimeException` you can catch it. I would suggest you put your whole code into `try{...}catch(Excepton ex){}`

Comment: I can catch it and it related to the "textbox.getText" in the try. I don't know how to avoid this but can catch it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just try wrapping the whole above code in `try catch` block as it seems **Exception** is not thrown from surrounded try block containing `System.out.println("try no "+attempts);`

```
try
{
    WebElement listbox = driver.findElement( By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountryList"));
    Select listboxSelect = new Select(listbox);

    //the textbox on the right
    WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountriesSelected"));


    int attempts = 0;
    while(textbox.getText() != Contry && attempts < 5)
    {
        attempts++;
        //make your selection in the select list
        listboxSelect.selectByVisibleText(Contry);

        //click the add button( or use the double click action )
        //addCountryButton.click();
        action3.perform();
        System.out.println("before the try");
        //wait for the textbox to be populated
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("try no "+attempts);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SiteDocumentUploadWizard_Wizard1_lsbCountriesSelected"), Contry));

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }catch (Error e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }catch (Error e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}catch (Error e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some exceptions only inherit `Throwable`try catching that one as well and see if it works.

Comment: He's catching Error as well. What else besides Error and Exception could be catched by Throwable?

Comment: Its a RuntimeException

Comment: RuntimeException inherit from Exception

Comment: So Exaception should catch it if it arrised with in `try-block`

Comment: All exceptions and errors are as far as I know based on `Throwable` so all things should be caught by catching throwable, assuming the exception/throwable is thrown in the try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementReferenceException` must then be a runtime exception and would have been caught in your try / catch block if it was thrown there.

Find line (`JavaExport.java:250`) in your code and ensure you try and catch it there.

Answer (score 0):

As this is selenium you need to make sure that the code is attempting to access exactly what you think it is accessing in the DOM..

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

More than likely it is the textBox.getText which is throwing the Exception, though this isn't clear without line numbers.

Comment: It is the textbox.getText that throwes the exception but how can I avoid this in my future coding ??

Comment: Check your findElement method calls for nulls before calling a get method on them. If they are null then there is a problem with the flow of your code. With selenium I have limited experience however likely the automated browser process has already moved on beyond where you think it has, ie the DOM is being searched by not finding the elements you expect to be there...